# LINQ to SQL Order By fails

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

Im having a little problem trying to Order By Row.TimeStamp which is a SQL DateTime.
I believe a picture says more than a Thousand words, so here is one! :)

[Picture](http://www.cdmapplications.be/pic.png)

As you can see it mixes other hours in it, i have googled allot before asking my question here.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
Using db As New basecontrollerEntities
    Dim query As List(Of tblLog) = (From Row In db.tblLogs Select Row Order By Row.TimeStamp Ascending).ToList
        For Each Item As tblLog In query
            AddToListview(Item)
        Next
End Using

Private Sub AddToListview(ByVal Row As tblLog)
    Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem(Row.TimeStamp)
    lvItem.SubItems.Add(Row.LogMessage)
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvItem)
End Sub
```

Comment: Dump the value of `query` before building the list. Is it ordered correctly?

Comment: Also  catch in SQL Profiler - what is the SQL Query being executed?

Comment: I tried not doing the .ToList but its stil the same.

Comment: Query : {SELECT " & vbCrLf & "[Extent1].[LogMessage] AS [LogMessage], " & vbCrLf & "[Extent1].[TimeStamp] AS [TimeStamp]" & vbCrLf & "FROM (SELECT " & vbLf & "      [tblLog].[LogMessage] AS [LogMessage], " & vbLf & "      [tblLog].[TimeStamp] AS [TimeStamp]" & vbLf & "      FROM [baseman].[tblLog] AS [tblLog]) AS [Extent1]" & vbCrLf & "ORDER BY [Extent1].[TimeStamp] ASC}

Comment: Anyone know what the problem is? im stil not finding the solution:-(